# MySQL (Beginner): Replace field from another table based on query answer

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, one with monster names and their respective scores:

```
CREATE TABLE `mobscores` (
  `name` TINYTEXT NOT NULL ,
  `score` TINYINT NOT NULL
);
```

and one with the actual kills on my server:

```
CREATE TABLE `mobkills` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `mob` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `item` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Now i could do the brute-force way and read the first table into a hash (Using Perl here, but that shouldn't matter for the question.), read in mobkills line for line after telling MySQL that i want the kills from one player starting at $whateverdate and then use the returning mob field on the hash to retrieve the score to add to the totals.
But i know that SQL is powerful so that i don't need to do that myself.
So, the question is, how do i tell MySQL to exchange, or even count together, the mob name for the score from table mobscores?

Something like this (fantasy syntax incoming as i don't know the real one):

```
SELECT score (AS score FROM mobscores WHERE name=mob) 
FROM mobkills 
WHERE name= 'McMiner' AND date >= SomeQueryDateToStartFrom;
```

I don't know if MySQL could even add up score for me so that i don't need to do that by foot in the Perl script, but that would be optional.
Thanks in advance. :)

EDIT:
Yay, thanks to rkosegis hint i got this. :D

```
SELECT name, sum( (SELECT score FROM mobscores WHERE mobscores.name = mobkills.mob)) 
as score 
FROM mobkills group by name order by score desc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT (SELECT sum(score) FROM mobscores WHERE mobscores.name = mobkills.name GROUP BY name) as Score
FROM mobkills 
WHERE name= 'McMiner' AND date >= SomeQueryDateToStartFrom;
```

Alternatively, you could use an inner join...